# Difference between "form" and "shape"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

What's the difference between *form* and *shape*?

I'm reading a philosophy book and these are used to denote different "things".  I considered these words as almost synonyms.

Comment: It would help if you could give us an example of how the words are used in the text.

Comment: It mentions "form and shape of light" often.

Comment: That sounds like it's just a turn of phrase to describe the way an object looks and feels. Does it ever use the two words in any other context that would imply a difference between the two?

Comment: You forgot ***way***. I'm sure everyone would agree that all 600,000 written instances of [(not) in any way shape or form](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22in+any+way+shape+or+form%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are "doubly tautological".

Comment: Could you include the *whole/entire sentence* with form and shape as an example, and add it to your question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the use of specific words in the context of philosophy.

Comment: I am tempted to up-vote this question as I believe it is useful, but I can hardly call it "clear". The OP, for the sake of clarity, should include a direct quote from the text in his question.

Comment: In art, I've seen _shape_ used to indicate a flat appearance, and _form_ for a volume (or the appearance of volume through shading).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention you are getting this out of a philosophy book, and I think the philosophical context is what might imply the difference. Philosophers might have a tendency to see "form" as reflecting the guiding principle of an object, or something connected with the meaning of it. "Form" used in this way carries a more or less vague linkage to the defining forces that cause a thing to be what it is. "Shape," on the other hand, is the more pedestrian, empirical identity, the recognizable structure of the thing.

This is also reflected in physics, wherein some "forms" of light might be (for example) *ultraviolet* or *infrared*, whereas a "shape" of light might be (again just for  example) "a circle."

Answer (score 1):

In large part, there are both approximately the same.  Form is usually a little bit more precise than shape though.

As an example, "He is roundish in shape, but has an otherwise refined form".

However, it's just as likely that "form and shape" is being used as an expression, rather than suggesting the two have any innate difference.

Comment: I think that last example would work with _shape_ and _form_ reversed. And I imagine it would have as much precise meaning that way, too.

Comment: You're probably right.  They are almost perfect synonyms.  I can make an argument for form being a more refined and definite form of shape, but there's not much evidence to support it.

Comment: I think we're ignoring the fact that "form" also means "type" or "class." Visible light and invisible light are two different forms. Ultraviolet light and infrared light are also two different forms (each one invisible to the naked eye, as it happens.) Many other examples abound.

Comment: Since AHD defines 26 polysemes / sub-polysemes for 'form' and Collins 29 (I can't be bothered checking 'shape' for you), I'm tempted to ask 'Shouldn't you first decide upon the difference between "form" and "form" (and "form"...)?'

Comment: The etymologies are interesting. _Form_ comes Gk _morphé_ 'the form by which a person or thing strikes the vision; external appearance', borrowed into Latin as _form_, same sense. _Shape_, on the other hand, comes from an old Germanic root that traces back to PIE (the Gk root for _morphé_ is unknown outside Greek, like _mint_, and may be borrowed from some other language). The root for _shape_ is from PIE _*(s)kep-_, glossed as 'Base of words with various technical meanings, including "to cut", "to scrape", "to hack".' There are many other English words from this root.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the words are used to indicate degree and relationship. My take on it is that *form* would be more essential and central to identity. *Shape* would refer to how that form manifests at the edges, how it is defined at the periphery. For example, you could have a *form* that looked almost like a star. When the edges of that form are further defined, the *shape* of a star emerges more clearly. Both are important in the observation and experience of the thing, but in slightly different ways.

However, philosophers can use terms in specific ways, with meanings that are different from those understood by the general public (and other philosophers). If that’s the case, you have to look to how the philosopher has set the meaning of those words (in the beginning chapters, at first mention of the words, or in other works).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this will depend greatly on the particular philosophy being presented.  For example, in Aristotelian and scholastic philosophy, "form" often means "substantial form" and is sometimes synonymous with "nature".  It is everything that determines what an entity is, except for the prime matter composing it. In the case of human beings, the substantial form is sometimes regarded as the same as the soul.  Obviously, this is very different from mere shape.  But there are many other philosophical systems, which may give "form" very different meanings.  [Experts on Aristotelian and scholastic philosophy are invited to edit this answer vigorously to improve my undoubtedly simplistic description.]

Comment: I'm tempted to say that shape is to form as shade is to color and as gesture is to motion, but that seems rather hollow.  Perhaps the point there is that the words are very nearly synonymous.